# Pure Virtual Function with Ifstream parameter, definition error?

Tags: c++

Hi I have a base class that is abstract with this code, its a file called BaseBallPlayer.h :

```
    #ifndef BASEBALLPLAYER_H
    #define BASEBALLPLAYER_H

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class BaseBallPlayer{


    protected:
        string name;
        int height;
        int weight;
    public:
    virtual void load_player(ifstream & read) = 0;  
    virtual ~BaseBallPlayer()=0;
```

I then have a derived class file Hitter.h which has

```
#ifndef HITTER_H
#define HITTER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "BaseBallPlayer.h"
using namespace std;

class Hitter : public BaseBallPlayer{
public:
virtual void load_player(ifstream &read);
~Hitter();
}
```

Now in my Hitter.cpp here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hitter.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void Hitter::load_player(ifstream & read){

    read >> name >> height >> weight;

    batAvg(hits, atBats);
}
```

I define the **virtual void load_player(ifstream &read)**
function but I keep getting an error where I have **read >>** And the error states no operator matches these operands >> 
Operand types are std::ifstream >> std::string

Basically the function will be called when I read in a file and store the info from the file in those variables. If possible I would like to do this in the function instead of writing separte code in main, but I cant use .open() with &ifstream. Anyway I'm just focused on this one error I have with the operands for now.

The reason why I am using a pure virtual function is because I have more than one derived class from my base class. I also have a pure virtual destructor in which later on I will add to the program with pointers and arrayList, but don't worry about that.

Please no vector solutions since I have never done too much of it.

Comment: did you include `<fstream>`? case in point https://ideone.com/epZIXG

Comment: No I did not, damn can't believe I forgot that . Also is it possible to open the file in my virtual function? Because I cannot use .open() with my &ifstream

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. Dependant on arguments, the file is opened in the constructor and closes when the ifstream object goes out of scope. In my example it opens when it's created in main and closes at the end of main.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you did in the example, thank you very much.